# taking control of an open browser instance

Tags: vba, vbscript

```
Set Browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

Once you create a new browser instance, how do you refer to that instance, instead of closing and reopening, say If I activate Excel window, then I want to activate back to the browser, how is this done?

I looked into

```
AppActivate "Windows Internet Explorer"
```

But If I have more than one window open, that wont work right, I dont think

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
Option Explicit
Public browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Sub NavigateTo()

   Set browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

   browser.Visible = True
   browser.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com"

End Sub
```

In other words, declare the browser variable at module level so it remains available.

You can also capture an instance like so:

```
Sub getIE()
Dim sh As Object, oWin As Object, IE As Object

    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    For Each oWin In sh.Windows
        If TypeName(oWin.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            Set IE = oWin
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print IE.Document.url
End Sub
```

Comment: My current workflow is: 1) Browser opens and authenticates 2) Automatically pulls specified data variables from Excel 3) Browser closes itself and goes back to excel But what if I want it to automate more data, and not have it authenticate every time? I just want to activate browser and use it from wherever it left off, how do I do that?

If I pull a row of data and process it, I want to go back to excel, have excel ask if more data needs to be processed, then use that current instance still left open to do it..  Hope I clarified

Comment: You can use either of the above examples, but the first one may suit best, that is, declare the variable at module level.

Comment: `Workbooks("test.xlsm").Activate`
 
 `browser.Activate`

Should there not be something like the above example, in order to go back to excel, and then back to browser again? Or I just call the browser regardless?

Comment: Why do you need to go back to Excel? Is the code not running in Excel? If it is, you have not left Excel.

Comment: I select from Column A, a number, whatever row that number is, pull that entire row contents, into variables, use those variables for automated data entry on a webform. I then want to go back into excel and have it ask if any more need to be input before closing the browser.  Otherwise, It would login everytime, and I do not want to log in to the account 100 times per day.  I guess the other way to do it, is to loop through past the authentication and ask me what numbers to take on the fly. What are your thoughts? Where is my weak point here?

Comment: If you are automating the data entry, you have never left Excel, so there is no need to go back. The browser is under the control of Excel. You do not even have to close it, you can just hide the instance.